# Getting the file path of layer based on layer name using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, geopackage, date, file-path

So  this is my folder:

[image]

It contains GeoPackages with the format `yyyymmdd_progress.gpkg`

I want to take the latest GeoPackage based on the latest GeoPackage created and stored in the folder, then use it as an input layer.

This is my script:

```py
import os

path_file = 'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Desktop\Sample Directory'

date = datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(2), "%Y%m%d") # or "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"
file_recent = path_file +'/'+f'{date}'+'_progress'+'.gpkg'

use_lay = file_recent.dataProvider().dataSourceUri()

lay1 = os.path.split(use_lay)

print(lay1)
```

[image]

Comment: Try path_file = 'C:\\Users\\CMCA\\OneDrive - Boskalis\\Desktop\\Sample Directory'

Answer (score 6):

You can use this script:

```py
from glob import glob
from datetime import datetime
from os.path import join, basename

folder = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Desktop\Sample Directory'

# extract date strings from filenames
dates = [basename(f).split("_")[0] for f in glob(join(folder, "*.gpkg"))] # -> [20230327, 20230328, 20230329]

# get the recent date from dates list
recent_date = max([datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d') for d in dates]) # -> datetime.datetime(2023, 3, 29, 0, 0)

# construct the recent file name
recent_file_path = join(folder, recent_date.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '_progress.gpkg') # -> /folder/20230329_progress.gpkg
print(recent_file_path)
```

Answer (score 4):

When you write

```py
path_file = 'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Desktop\Sample Directory'
```

the Python interpreter will treat the backslashes as control characters. It will try to decode a Unicode control sequence (`\u`)called `sers`, which does not exist.

```py
path_file = r'C:\Users\CMCA\OneDrive - Boskalis\Desktop\Sample Directory'
```

will work.

The `r'...'` in the definition of the `path_file` string means "raw string", that is the backslashes are used as-is and not as control characters, which would be the default behaviour in Python strings. `'c:\test'` is interpreted as "c:" followed by a tabulator character, followed by "est". `r'c:\test'` is interpreted as "c:\test". In `'c:\\test'` the backslash is doubled (escaped) and so this will also evaluate to "c:\test". See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals for *all* the details.

See this example in Python:

```py
>>> print("\U0001F3F3\uFE0F")
️
>>> print(r"\U0001F3F3\uFE0F")
\U0001F3F3\uFE0F
```